# apache 2.4 on debian squeeze via apt

Tags: debian, apt, debian-squeeze, apache-2.4

Is there a source like dotdeb.org which offers the apache 2.4 packages for Debian squeeze? I'm looking for Apache modules. I want to install the modules from this source and then the actual version of apache via apt?

Comment: "so that I can install php stuff" Please when asking a question be specific what you want. Do you want to install php or the php modules for Apache?

Comment: ok i edited my questio. I want to install the module for apache

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any repo with apache 2.4 for Squeeze. I have tried to build it with modified dependencies.

Download debian sources:

```
apt-get source apache2 -t experimental
```

Modify dependencies in debian/control to older ones - available in Squeeze:

```
debhelper (>= 8.0.0~), dpkg-dev (>= 1.15.8.12~), libaprutil1-dev (>= 1.3.9))
```

And build it:

```
cd apache2-2.4.2/ && dpkg-buildpackage -b
```

Install with `dpkg -i`, it will need some more packages.

Comment: How did that workout for you? Was there any problems?